# Credit card chip read error

Tags: android, smartcard, contactless-smartcard, emv

I am developing an interface to read information from credit cards using an android device with NFC and Smartcard/Chip reader. With this card I can read the information using NFC but when using the chip reader I get different errors such "6E 00 -- Class not supported" or " 69 85 -- Conditions of use not satisfied" . First APDU are fine but after sending  "80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00" I get the errors. Please see below complete unsuccessful APDU messages flow:

```
       transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 0e 32 50 41 59 2e 53 59 53 2e 44 44 46 30 31 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 0e 32 50 41 59 2e 53 59 53 2e 44 44 46 30 31 00,tw:3
   tmpTransTimeout(3):0
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:91,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6f 57 84 0e 32 50 41 59 2e 53 59 53 2e 44 44 46 30 31 a5 45 bf 0c 42 61 1b 4f 07 a0 00 00 00 42 10 10 50 02 43 42 87 01 01 9f 2a 08 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 61 23 4f 07 a0 00 00 00 04 10 10 50 0a 4d 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 87 01 02 9f 2a 08 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00
    resp: 6F 57 84 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 45 BF 0C 42 61 1B 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 50 02 43 42 87 01 01 9F 2A 08 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 61 23 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 50 0A 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 87 01 02 9F 2A 08 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00
    resp: 
    6F 57 -- File Control Information (FCI) Template
          84 0E -- Dedicated File (DF) Name
                32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 (BINARY)
          A5 45 -- File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
                BF 0C 42 -- File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
                         61 1B -- Application Template
                               4F 07 -- Application Identifier (AID) - card
                                     A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 (BINARY)
                               50 02 -- Application Label
                                     43 42 (=CB)
                               87 01 -- Application Priority Indicator
                                     01 (BINARY)
                               9F 2A 08 -- The value to be appended to the ADF Name in the data field of the SELECT command, if the Extended Selection Support flag is present and set to 1
                                        02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (BINARY)
                         61 23 -- Application Template
                               4F 07 -- Application Identifier (AID) - card
                                     A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 (BINARY)
                               50 0A -- Application Label
                                     4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 (=MASTERCARD)
                               87 01 -- Application Priority Indicator
                                     02 (BINARY)
                               9F 2A 08 -- The value to be appended to the ADF Name in the data field of the SELECT command, if the Extended Selection Support flag is present and set to 1
                                        02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (BINARY)
    90 00 -- Command successfully executed (OK)
    resp: Command successfully executed (OK)
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 42 10 10 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 42 10 10 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:63,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6f 3b 84 07 a0 00 00 00 42 10 10 a5 30 50 02 43 42 87 01 01 9f 11 01 01 9f 12 0e 54 72 61 6e 73 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 20 43 42 5f 2d 04 66 72 65 6e bf 0c 0a df 60 02 0b 14 9f 4d 02 0b 14 90 00
    resp: 6F 3B 84 07 A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 A5 30 50 02 43 42 87 01 01 9F 11 01 01 9F 12 0E 54 72 61 6E 73 61 63 74 69 6F 6E 20 43 42 5F 2D 04 66 72 65 6E BF 0C 0A DF 60 02 0B 14 9F 4D 02 0B 14 90 00
    resp: 
    6F 3B -- File Control Information (FCI) Template
          84 07 -- Dedicated File (DF) Name
                A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 (BINARY)
          A5 30 -- File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
                50 02 -- Application Label
                      43 42 (=CB)
                87 01 -- Application Priority Indicator
                      01 (BINARY)
                9F 11 01 -- Issuer Code Table Index
                         01 (NUMERIC)
                9F 12 0E -- Application Preferred Name
                         54 72 61 6E 73 61 63 74 69 6F 6E 20 43 42 (=Transaction CB)
                5F 2D 04 -- Language Preference
                         66 72 65 6E (=fren)
                BF 0C 0A -- File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
                         DF 60 02 -- VISA Log Entry
                                  0B 14 (BINARY)
                         9F 4D 02 -- Log Entry
                                  0B 14 (BINARY)
    90 00 -- Command successfully executed (OK)
    resp: Command successfully executed (OK)
   transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6e 00
    resp: 6E 00
    resp: 
    6E 00 -- Class not supported
    resp: Class not supported
   transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 69 85
    resp: 69 85
    resp: 
    69 85 -- Conditions of use not satisfied
    resp: Conditions of use not satisfied
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 0f a0 00 00 00 42 10 10 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 0f a0 00 00 00 42 10 10 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 04 10 10 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 04 10 10 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:67,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6f 3f 84 07 a0 00 00 00 04 10 10 a5 34 50 0a 4d 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 87 01 02 9f 11 01 01 9f 12 0a 4d 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 5f 2d 04 66 72 65 6e bf 0c 0a df 60 02 0b 14 9f 4d 02 0b 14 90 00
    resp: 6F 3F 84 07 A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 A5 34 50 0A 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 87 01 02 9F 11 01 01 9F 12 0A 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 5F 2D 04 66 72 65 6E BF 0C 0A DF 60 02 0B 14 9F 4D 02 0B 14 90 00
    resp: 
    6F 3F -- File Control Information (FCI) Template
          84 07 -- Dedicated File (DF) Name
                A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 (BINARY)
          A5 34 -- File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
                50 0A -- Application Label
                      4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 (=MASTERCARD)
                87 01 -- Application Priority Indicator
                      02 (BINARY)
                9F 11 01 -- Issuer Code Table Index
                         01 (NUMERIC)
                9F 12 0A -- Application Preferred Name
                         4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 (=MASTERCARD)
                5F 2D 04 -- Language Preference
                         66 72 65 6E (=fren)
                BF 0C 0A -- File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
                         DF 60 02 -- VISA Log Entry
                                  0B 14 (BINARY)
                         9F 4D 02 -- Log Entry
                                  0B 14 (BINARY)
    90 00 -- Command successfully executed (OK)
    resp: Command successfully executed (OK)
   transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6e 00
    resp: 6E 00
    resp: 
    6E 00 -- Class not supported
    resp: Class not supported
   transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 69 85
    resp: 69 85
    resp: 
    69 85 -- Conditions of use not satisfied
    resp: Conditions of use not satisfied
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 0f a0 00 00 00 04 10 10 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 0f a0 00 00 00 04 10 10 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 03 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 03 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 98 08 48 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 98 08 48 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 04 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 04 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:67,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6f 3f 84 07 a0 00 00 00 04 10 10 a5 34 50 0a 4d 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 87 01 02 9f 11 01 01 9f 12 0a 4d 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 5f 2d 04 66 72 65 6e bf 0c 0a df 60 02 0b 14 9f 4d 02 0b 14 90 00
    resp: 6F 3F 84 07 A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 A5 34 50 0A 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 87 01 02 9F 11 01 01 9F 12 0A 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 5F 2D 04 66 72 65 6E BF 0C 0A DF 60 02 0B 14 9F 4D 02 0B 14 90 00
    resp: 
    6F 3F -- File Control Information (FCI) Template
          84 07 -- Dedicated File (DF) Name
                A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 (BINARY)
          A5 34 -- File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
                50 0A -- Application Label
                      4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 (=MASTERCARD)
                87 01 -- Application Priority Indicator
                      02 (BINARY)
                9F 11 01 -- Issuer Code Table Index
                         01 (NUMERIC)
                9F 12 0A -- Application Preferred Name
                         4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 (=MASTERCARD)
                5F 2D 04 -- Language Preference
                         66 72 65 6E (=fren)
                BF 0C 0A -- File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
                         DF 60 02 -- VISA Log Entry
                                  0B 14 (BINARY)
                         9F 4D 02 -- Log Entry
                                  0B 14 (BINARY)
    90 00 -- Command successfully executed (OK)
    resp: Command successfully executed (OK)
   transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6e 00
    resp: 6E 00
    resp: 
    6E 00 -- Class not supported
    resp: Class not supported
   transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 69 85
    resp: 69 85
    resp: 
    69 85 -- Conditions of use not satisfied
    resp: Conditions of use not satisfied
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 05 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 05 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 25 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 25 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 42 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 42 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:63,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6f 3b 84 07 a0 00 00 00 42 10 10 a5 30 50 02 43 42 87 01 01 9f 11 01 01 9f 12 0e 54 72 61 6e 73 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 20 43 42 5f 2d 04 66 72 65 6e bf 0c 0a df 60 02 0b 14 9f 4d 02 0b 14 90 00
    resp: 6F 3B 84 07 A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 A5 30 50 02 43 42 87 01 01 9F 11 01 01 9F 12 0E 54 72 61 6E 73 61 63 74 69 6F 6E 20 43 42 5F 2D 04 66 72 65 6E BF 0C 0A DF 60 02 0B 14 9F 4D 02 0B 14 90 00
    resp: 
    6F 3B -- File Control Information (FCI) Template
          84 07 -- Dedicated File (DF) Name
                A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 (BINARY)
          A5 30 -- File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
                50 02 -- Application Label
                      43 42 (=CB)
                87 01 -- Application Priority Indicator
                      01 (BINARY)
                9F 11 01 -- Issuer Code Table Index
                         01 (NUMERIC)
                9F 12 0E -- Application Preferred Name
                         54 72 61 6E 73 61 63 74 69 6F 6E 20 43 42 (=Transaction CB)
                5F 2D 04 -- Language Preference
                         66 72 65 6E (=fren)
                BF 0C 0A -- File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
                         DF 60 02 -- VISA Log Entry
                                  0B 14 (BINARY)
                         9F 4D 02 -- Log Entry
                                  0B 14 (BINARY)
    90 00 -- Command successfully executed (OK)
    resp: Command successfully executed (OK)
   transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6e 00
    resp: 6E 00
    resp: 
    6E 00 -- Class not supported
    resp: Class not supported
   transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 69 85
    resp: 69 85
    resp: 
    69 85 -- Conditions of use not satisfied
    resp: Conditions of use not satisfied
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 29 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 29 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 65 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 00 65 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 01 21 10 10 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 01 21 10 10 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 01 41 00 01 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 01 41 00 01 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 01 52 30 10 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 01 52 30 10 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 01 54 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 01 54 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 02 28 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 02 28 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 02 77 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 02 77 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 03 24 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 03 24 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 03 33 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 03 33 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 03 59 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 03 59 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 03 71 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 03 71 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 04 39 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 04 39 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 05 24 10 10 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 05 24 10 10 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 04 32 00 01 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 04 32 00 01 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 09 d2 76 00 00 25 45 50 01 00 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 09 d2 76 00 00 25 45 50 01 00 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 d5 78 00 00 02 10 10 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 d5 78 00 00 02 10 10 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 f0 00 00 00 03 00 01 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 f0 00 00 00 03 00 01 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 06 a0 00 00 00 24 01 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 06 a0 00 00 00 24 01 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 01 21 10 10 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 01 21 10 10 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 04 54 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 05 a0 00 00 04 54 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 06 a0 00 00 04 76 6c 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 06 a0 00 00 04 76 6c 00,tw:3
   isIccInsert:1
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   transceive(3) in: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 03 71 00 01 00
   SendAPDU data: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 03 71 00 01 00,tw:3
   SendAPDU ret:0,outlen:2,tw:3
   picc transceive success!
   transceive out: 6a 82
    resp: 6A 82
    resp: 
    6A 82 -- File not found
    resp: File not found
   reconnect
```

Comment: Have you gone through its card application specification ? In case you have the same in English, do share here. This is a not a very common application like Visa or MasterCard. The first byte of an APDU is its class and the GET PO error shows the class 80 is not supported. Just out of curiosity, can you try 00 instead for testing and see what happens.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean with "Have you gone through its card application specification"

Comment: Every application will have its application specification document which will detail on its functioning. GET PO command what you issued is fine as per EMV standards, but still it is rejected. So it is better to check the corresponding application specification manuals on what situations you will run into what errors. It will have also detailed info on its state machine behavior.

Comment: response to 00a8000002830000 is 6E00 -Class not supported and 80a8000002830000 is 6985 -Conditions of use not satisfied

Comment: @libemv.so.1.0.1 sorry, why did you think it is a not a very common application? It is a french CIC CB Mastercard card

Comment: In your original logs transceive(3) in: 80 a8 00 00 02 83 00 00 was giving transceive out: 6e 00. But as per your last update when you try with 80 A8 gave you 6985. Which is correct ? In get processing options you can get 6985 in two cases (1) when PDOL data is incorrect (2) application is disabled. Are you sure it is working in contactless mode as mentioned initially, is it the same card ?

Comment: is the same card, the card is inserted on the chip reader

Answer (score 0):

According to the Specification (V4.3 Book 1 Table 43) your FCI after reading the PSE should contain a mandatory field with Tag **88** (SFI), 
so i don't really understand your FCI. It is missing a mandatory field (tag 88). Are you sure of that response you posted?. See Table 43 Book 1 v4.3. Which specification are you using?. Also to get the application of your card you can use for transaction, would require you to proceed as in Book 1 chapter 12.3.2. From which you might actually find out that your application provide a PDOL, which you have to provide before you can successfully read the processing options. That is why you might be getting 69 85.